# Image upload form inside larger form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that allows users to create events. Inside this form I have a form for an image upload. The **HTML** looks like this:

```
<form id="upload_event" method="post" action="system/upload_event.php">

<input type="text" name="title">
<textarea name="description"></textarea>

<form id="upload_image" method="post" action="system/upload_image.php">
<!-- code -->
</form>

<a href="#">Upload event</a>
<input style="display:none" type="submit" id="submit_upload_event" name="submit_upload_event">

</form>
```

This is what my **upload_image.php**, which processes the image upload, looks like:

```
// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}

echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

As I found out, it is not possible to nest a form into another one. What would be the solution here?

Comment: Put it into one form and merge `.php` files.

Comment: Why do you need a different form when `input type="file"` does it straight up?

Comment: in my larger form I want to do a header-redirect with post. for my image upload i want to have an ajax upload, that's why there is an extra upload_image.php  So I am not sure if it is possible to merge both php scripts

Comment: You can't have a `form` in a `form`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ajax you could return a value from your upload form to your main form. Like putvande said you can't have a form inside a form.